React Native - How to navigate to a specific screen in a child stack navigator from a parent drawer navigator
I have not been able to achieve this for days now.
My topmost navigator is a DrawerNavigator and it has multiple links to the a particular child Stack navigator but also to other screens.
This is my parent drawer navigator:
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function MainLayout() {
    ...

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Inicio" screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false,
                drawerPosition: "right",
                drawerType: "slide",
                drawerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: '#01414d'
                },
                drawerInactiveTintColor: '#fff',
                drawerActiveTintColor: '#fff',
                drawerActiveBackgroundColor: '#7fa091',
                drawerLabelStyle: {
                    fontFamily: "Figtree-SemiBold",
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: '#fff'
                },
            }}>
                <Drawer.Screen name="Inicio" component={PublicLayout} initialParams={{ route: 'Home' }} options={{
                    drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
                        <Text style={[css.icon, { color: color, marginRight: -23, width: 20, textAlign: 'center' }]}>{" "}{FontAwesome.fa_house}</Text>
                    )
                }} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Contacto" component={PublicLayout} initialParams={{ route: 'Contact' }} options={{
                    drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
                        <Text style={[css.icon, { color: color, marginRight: -23, width: 20, textAlign: 'center' }]}>{" "}{FontAwesome.fa_phone_office}</Text>
                    )
                }} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Mi cuenta" component={PrivateLayout} options={{
                    drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
                        <Text style={[css.icon, { color: color, marginRight: -23, width: 20, textAlign: 'center' }]}>{" "}{FontAwesome.fa_user}</Text>
                    )
                }} />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}

And this is my child StackNavigator:
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function PublicLayout({ route, navigation }) {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" screenOptions={{ header: Header }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Vehicle" component={VehicleScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Financing" component={FinancingScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Contact" component={ContactScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

I have tried custom drawer items but seems like a very convoluted way of doing things...
I tried setting the initialRouteName to the "route" parameter i send and it doesnt work.
I have been banging my head against this problem for a while, I could really use a hand with this.

with custom drawer items you'd achieve this with just a few lines... what's convoluted? you render a component with an onPress where you can write the navigation logic you want.

It just seems silly that Drawer.Screen nodes wouldn't have a onPress override or something of the sort, the documentation is all over the place so I figured I could be missing something... if this is not possible to do with basic Drawer.Screen nodes, I'll do it with custom drawer items

seems you have a misunderstanding of what Drawer.Screen is. it's purpose is to add screens to the drawer navigator - so that you can navigate to them, not to add to the sidebar. by default the sidebar shows all the screens available in the navigator, but you could choose not to, or hide some of the items, or add extra items etc. which is independent of what screens are available for navigation. if you want to navigate to a nested screen then that screen is not part of the drawer navigator.

drawer screen does have a drawerItemPress event - but to be able to what you want you'll have to add a screen to the drawer that's essentially blank and renders nothing - which is more convoluted than just adding another item in the sidebar - which is what you wanted to do in the first place.

I understand now, thank you very much.

It seems i have misunderstood the purpose of the Drawer.Screen items, while they provide a quick way to add items to the menu, what I need can only be achievable through the use of Custom Drawer Items.
Thanks @satya164 for the answer.
